# Distance between position in List of Ngrams

Tags: c#

I need to make a distance between the position of a element in one list with the same element in another list.

i´ve tried something like this

```
 public void out_of_place(List<NgramItem> Test, List<NgramItem> Train)
   {
       List<int> result = new List<int>();
       int indexTest = -1;
       int indexTrain = -1;

           foreach (NgramItem item in Test) {         
           indexTest = Test.IndexOf(item);
           indexTrain = Train.IndexOf(item);                 
           }
           Console.WriteLine(" Index: {0}   {1}", indexTest, indexTrain);

    }
```

public class NgramItem : IComparable 
    {
        private string ngram ;
        private int frequency ;
        // ...
    }

but i can not get the index of the item on the list Train. 
There is anybosy some gets i suggestion?

Thanks

Comment: Is it the same object or just the same id?

Comment: Could you show us more code and provide more information? What is `NgramItem`? How are `Test` and `Train` defined and how are they filled? There doesn't seem to be anything wrong with the code you posted. What does `Train.IndexOf()` return?

Comment: NgramItem is an class with ngram(word) e its frequency. test and train are List<NgramItem> and they are filled. indexOf() fives you the index of a a specific elemten of the collection

Answer (score 1):

You have not given any details of the collection type used or `NgramItem`. However, it is quite likely that doing `Train.IndexOf(item)` will use default `Equals` for reference types and that is `ReferenceEquals`. Unless the instances are shared in the two collections `IndexOf` will always return -1 because the instances of `Test` are not stored in `Train`.

A solution is to implement `Equals` on `NgramItem` to determine if two instances of `NgramItem` represent the same value. Remember that if you override `Equals` you also have to override `GetHashCode`.

Comment: NgramItem is an object define by me. You can see it like words and the frequency of the word. The ideia is to calculate for each word from Test, its distance from the same word in the Train list.
example:  Test  = A B C D  Train = D C A B .the distance would be something like this : 2 2 1 3.

Comment: Martin you are rigth, i just get -1 from the index of Train. I will try to implement Equals.

Comment: I have tried your soluction but it still not working... Thanks anyway.

Comment: Tips for unit testing: Create two instances `a` and `b` of `NgramItem` that are equal. Verify that `a.Equals(b)` returns true. Then add `b` to a collection `c` and verify that `c.IndexOf(a)` returns a non-negative number.